# Incorrect column display in the table

Tags: two-column

Help me please, I'm new here:(

```
\begin{table}
 \caption{Porovnání technologií ASP.NET a ASP.NET Core \cite{compare-asp} }
  \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        ASP.NET  & ASP.NET Core \\
        \hline
        Funguje na Windows  & Funguje na Windows, Linux, Mac \\
        \hline
       Používá Web Forms, SignalR, \\ MVC, Web API, Web Pages & Používá Razor Pages(doporučeno), \\ MVC, Web API, SignalR\\
        \hline
        Jedna verze na zařízení & Více verzí na jednom zařízení\\
        \hline
        Dobrý výkon & Výkon je větší než ASP.NET\\
        \hline
        Používá .NET framework  & Používá .NET Core nebo .NET framework\\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `\\` for linebreaks inside cells. With the `tabularx` package, you could have tex do the linebreaks for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Porovnání technologií ASP.NET a ASP.NET Core}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
        \hline
        ASP.NET  & ASP.NET Core \\
        \hline
        Funguje na Windows  & Funguje na Windows, Linux, Mac \\
        \hline
       Používá Web Forms, SignalR, MVC, Web API, Web Pages & Používá Razor Pages(doporučeno), MVC, Web API, SignalR\\
        \hline
        Jedna verze na zařízení & Více verzí na jednom zařízení\\
        \hline
        Dobrý výkon & Výkon je větší než ASP.NET\\
        \hline
        Používá .NET framework  & Používá .NET Core nebo .NET framework\\
        \hline
      \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

---

I suggest to use the `booktabs` package for a nicer layout

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \caption{Porovnání technologií ASP.NET a ASP.NET Core}
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}p{5cm}X@{}}
        \toprule
        ASP.NET  & ASP.NET Core \\
        \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(l){2-2}
        Funguje na Windows  & Funguje na Windows, Linux, Mac \\\addlinespace
       Používá Web Forms, SignalR, MVC, Web API, Web Pages & Používá Razor Pages(doporučeno), MVC, Web API, SignalR\\\addlinespace
        Jedna verze na zařízení & Více verzí na jednom zařízení\\\addlinespace
        Dobrý výkon & Výkon je větší než ASP.NET\\\addlinespace
        Používá .NET framework  & Používá .NET Core nebo .NET framework\\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need it with borders, can edit your code please. Anyway thanks so much for help!

Comment: @KonstantinKožuchov my first answer has borders